# iOs5, Trying to understand the UIPickerView and how to connect it to my custom class

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uipickerview

Ok I am trying to connect a `UIPickerView` with a custom class. The idea is to have 3 picker views in one normal view.

1. So far I have created one view and bound it to my class TestView.h
2. Then I added a picker view to the view in the storyboard (iOS 5)
3. I then created a class for this picker view:

   ```
   @interface TestPickerView : UIPickerView <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> 
   {  
     NSArray *data;  
   }
   ```
4. Then tried to add a Property to my normal view (TestView.h)

   ```
   #import "TestPickerView.h"
   @interface TestView : UIViewController
     @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet TestPickerView *myTestPicker;
   @end
   ```

But how do i bind the UIPickerView inside my normal view to this class/property?

I will in the end have 3 UIPickerView's and my idea was to have 3 references in my `UIViewController` to control these `UIPickerViews`. That way I could set the data (datasource) using the properties once when the normal view is loading and then the PickerViews would just show. Hopefully i would also be able to get notified in my normal view when the value in one of the views occur.

Comment: Why can not you create three properties of PickerView of your TestPickerView class and add it to your view.

Comment: And how do i then know which picker that wants what data? and what picker value that has been changed?

Comment: Based on pickerView index, you can identify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please call your `TestView` >> `TestViewController` instead, as it is a controller.

In your storyboard, select the PickerView and change it's class name to `TestPickerView`.

[image] 
[image]

After that just create your three `IBOutlets` and connect the PickerViews. That's it.

// edit: To explain, how you distinguish between the pickers. Make 3 outlets, e.g.:

```
IBOutlet TestPickerView *picker1;
IBOutlet TestPickerView *picker2;
IBOutlet TestPickerView *picker3;
```

And than in your delegate method, check which picker did call the delegate, e.g.:

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if(pickerView == self.picker1)
    {
        // picker1
    }
    else if(pickerView == self.picker2)
    {
        // picker2
    }
    else
    {
        // picker3
    }
}
```

Comment: and how do i know what pickerview that is calling for data (datasource)? and that has its value changed?
In the end, it will be 3 pickers in the same UIViewController.

Comment: The picker view sending the delegate message passes itself as one of the arguments. Compare that object to the property on your class to know which picker you're dealing with.

Comment: Am I missing something, what is the subclass of UIPickerView for?

Comment: @jrturton, I was wondering the same thing. At first I thought a subclass would be cleaner, but by the time I get done passing arguments to and fro, I do not think that will be the case. Does anyone have a good reason for the subclass?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go dude, this is how I did it on several of my apps and games.

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #pragma mark - Delegate Protocol 
    @protocol someDelegate
    @required
    -(void)somePickerFinishedPicking:(id)item;
    @end

    #pragma mark - Class interface 
    @interface SomePicker : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource>
    {
        NSMutableArray* dataSource;
    }

    #pragma mark - Property Istantiation 

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* dataSource;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) id <someDelegate> pickDelegate;

    #pragma mark - Constructors / Destructors

    - (id)   initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
    - (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning;
    - (void) dealloc;
    - (void) createDataSource;

    #pragma mark - View Lifecycle
    - (void) viewDidLoad;

    #pragma mark - UIPicker Protocols

    -(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    -(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
    -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component;
    -(UIView*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view;

    #pragma mark - Delegate Protocols

    -(void) handlePickerDidFinish:(id)item;

    @end
```

this for your .m

```
#pragma mark - Class Implementation 
@implementation SomePicker

#pragma mark - Variable synthesize 
// ARRAYS
@synthesize dataSource;

// DELEGATES
@synthesize pickDelegate = _pickDelegate;

#pragma mark - Constructors / Deconstructors 
// Class initialization
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        dataSource = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [self createDataSource];
    }
    return self;
}

// Handles memory warning events
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Release the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

// Garbage Collection
- (void) dealloc;
{
    // Release what you need
    self.dataSource = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

// Creates the occasion entries for the picker
-(void)createDataSource
{
    NSMutableDictionary* dataDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    // create your data source here or just forget about this and pass it from the parentViewController.
    [dataDictionary release];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad;
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPickerView* occasionsPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    [occasionsPicker setDataSource:self];
    [occasionsPicker setDelegate:self];
    [occasionsPicker setTag:888];
    [occasionsPicker selectRow:500 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
    [self.view addSubview:occasionsPicker];
    [occasionsPicker release];

    [self handlePickerDidFinish:[[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:(500 % self.dataSource.count)] objectForKey:@"key"]];
}

#pragma mark - UIPicker Protocols

// Creates the rows in the picker.
-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{   
    // Endless roll illusion else just bind it to the size of the data source
    return 1000;
}

// Determines the number of columns in the picker
-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    // Add however many columns you need
    return 1;
}

// Handles the event when the user picks a row.
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    //this does something with the row selected
    [self handlePickerDidFinish:[[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:(row % self.dataSource.count)] objectForKey:@"key"]];
}

// Creates the custom view for each cell so the text shows in accordance to the App Style
-(UIView*) pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    UILabel* customRowLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].width, [pickerView rowSizeForComponent:component].height)] autorelease];

    customRowLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size: 16];
    customRowLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:kColorRed green:kColorGreen blue:kColorBlue alpha:1];
    customRowLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    customRowLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    customRowLabel.text = [[self.dataSource objectAtIndex:(row % self.dataSource.count)] objectForKey:@"key"];

    return customRowLabel;
}

#pragma mark - Delegate Protocols 
// Notifies Delegate class that an action has been perfomed and passes the Mood String selected
-(void)handlePickerDidFinish:(id)item
{
    [self.pickDelegate somePickerFinishedPicking:item];
}

@end
```

And just instantiate it like so on your parent ViewController:

```
CGRect rectPicker = CGRectMake(60, 100, 200, 216);
self.somePicker = [[[SomePicker alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.somePicker setPickDelegate:self];
[self.somePicker.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
self.somePicker.view.frame = rectPicker;
[self.somePicker.view setTag:777];
[self.somePicker.view setAlpha:0];
[self.view addSubview:self.somePicker.view];
```

~/End of Line

Comment: Note This is for one picker, but you can add as many as you want. just instantiate them using the last bit

Comment: Will experiment with this and see if i can get it to work. How do i pass the picker data to the picker and how do i catch when a picker has been changed. (I mean, what picker that was actually changed).

Comment: Sorry a bit new to iPhone programming.

Comment: I didn't use storyboards for that particular example, I instantiated them programatically.